# Immediate functions and different declarative syntaxes

Tags: javascript

Regarding immediate function in JS. What is the difference between this syntax

```
(function() {}());
```

and

```
(function() {})();
```

I especially do not understand the use of the last part `()` in the second example.

Could you provide me a quick explanation together with a sample of code on how to use an immediate function with this different syntax?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this question!

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-5-functions/#question-about-surrounding-parentheses